# Error when program is run (Python)

Tags: python

I have a problem with my program, is it possible for anyone to help me fix it?

Aim:

In input.txt:

```
7 12
100
```

Output.txt:

```
84 16
```

84 is from 7*12 and 16 is from 100-84

This is my current code:

```
with open('sitin.txt', 'r') as inpt:
    numberone = inpt.readlines()[0].split(' ') # Reads and splits numbers in the first line of the txt
    numbertwo = inpt.readlines()[1] # Reads the second line of the txt file

product = int(numberone[0])*int(numberone[1]) # Calculates the product
remainder = int(numbertwo)-product # Calculates the remainder using variable seats

with open('sitout.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write(str(product) + ' ' + str(remainder)) # Writes the results into the txt
```

It doesn't output anything.
Could someone help?
Thanks in advance for anyone's help!

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: @BenT How do can I see? When I open it, the box disappears too fast for me to read an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `inpt.readlines()`, you fully read through the contents of the file `sitin.txt` such that subsequent calls to `readlines()` will return an empty arrary `[]`.

To avoid this issue with multiple reads, you can save the file contents to a variable on the first read and then parse the different lines as needed:

```
with open('sitin.txt', 'r') as inpt:
    contents = inpt.readlines()
    numberone = contents[0].split(' ')
    numbertwo = contents[1]

product = int(numberone[0])*int(numberone[1])
remainder = int(numbertwo) - product

with open('sitout.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write(str(product) + ' ' + str(remainder))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider what's happening:

```
with open('sitin.txt', 'r') as inpt:
    # read *all* of the lines and then take the first one and split it
    numberone = inpt.readlines()[0].split(' ')

    # oh dear, we read all the lines already, what will inpt.readlines() do?
    numbertwo = inpt.readlines()[1] # Reads the second line of the txt file
```

I'm sure you can solve the remainder of your homework with this hint.

Comment: Ohhhh! Thank you so much!
So I just added another 

    with open('sitin.txt', 'r') as inpt 
after I define numberone.

Tysm for the help!